# Application Requester Routing WCF Service error 404

Tags: web-services, wcf, http-status-code-404, arr

We migrated our outdated ARR to an High Availability ARR solution. The problem we are facing now is on a WCF web service.

When I navigate to [www.company.com/webservice/service1.svc](http://www.company.com/webservice/service1.svc) I get the error:

> Server Error in '/' Application. The resource cannot be found.
> Description: HTTP 404. The resource you are looking for (or one of its
> dependencies) could have been removed, had its name changed, or is
> temporarily unavailable.  Please review the following URL and make
> sure that it is spelled correctly.

If I navigate to [www.company.com/webservice/](http://www.company.com/webservice/) I can see all the files including service1.svc.

Any pointers to where to look? I cannot figure it out.

Appreciate your time

Comment: `If I navigate to www.company.com/webservice/ I can see all the files including service1.svc.` Have you tried to click on the service1.svc file and check if the same error is reported

Comment: Yes, if I clicked on the file it would throw the same error.

Comment: Adding  <system.serviceModel>
     <serviceHostingEnvironment aspNetCompatibilityEnabled="true" multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true" />
 </system.serviceModel>

To web.config solved the problem.